Getting the raw data from google drive using google api
I'm trying to make a "GET" data(folder Name, ID , type etc) from my google drive using googleapis
I'm using this code
const fetchGoogleDriveFiles = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'&fields=files(id,name,mimeType,parents)`,
        {
          method: "GET", 
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${session.accessToken}`,
          },
        }
      ); 
      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log("Google Drive Files:", data.files);
      } else {
        console.error("Error fetching Google Drive files:", response.status);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching Google Drive files:", error);
    }
  };

while this code, do get data, however the data it is "GETTING" is data the i have previously uploaded using a upload function. What i want and plan to do is, get all the data that already exists inside my drive such as folder name, id, memtype etc etc
im using a API route for my authentication and such
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"
export const authOptions = ({
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId : process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID ?? "" ,
            clientSecret : process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET ?? "",
            authorization: { 
              params: 
              { 
                scope: "openid email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file" 
                //
              } 
            },
        })
    ],
    callbacks: {
      async jwt({token, user , account} : any){  
        if (account) {
          token.accessToken = account.access_token;
        }
        return token
      },
      async session({ session, token } : any) {
        const newSession = {
          ...session,
          accessToken: token.accessToken,
        }; 
        return newSession;
      },
    }
})
 
const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)
export {handler as GET, handler as POST}

can anyone help me out here? i dont seem to get it properly

I don't understand what you're asking.  What's the difference between "data that I have previously uploaded" and "data that already exists inside my drive"?  There isn't anything in your Drive that you didn't upload.

About your scope of https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file, in this scope, you can retrieve only the files and folders which were created by the same client. About get all the data that already exists inside my drive such as folder name, id, memtype etc etc, if you want to retrieve only the file metadata, please use the scope of https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly instead of https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file. And try it again. By the way, in your query parameters, the metadata of only 100 folders is returned. Please be careful about this.

yeah, sorry bout that, my drive already contains sample files data that I plan to retrieve using googleapis GET, but since i have a upload function, the data that i uploaded using that is the only thing that im retrieving, while the data the already existed inside my drive is not being retrieved HOPE that made sense
also i will try the scopes you mentions, THANKS!! on that

@Tanaike thanks, it was very very helpful hahahaha, MUCH PRECIATED

@user14670265 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. From your reply, in order to be useful for other users too, I posted it as an answer by summarizing. Please confirm it.

Your scope of https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file retrieves only the files and folders that were created by the same client.
When you want to achieve your goal of get all the data that already exists inside my drive such as folder name, id, memtype etc etc, it is required to change the scope as follows.
From:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file

To:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly

In this scope, only the file metadata of all files and folders is returned. If you want to retrieve both the file metadata and the file content, please use https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly. If you want to upload and download the file content and the file metadata including all files and folders, please use https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.
Note:

As additional information, in your query parameters, the metadata of only 100 folders is returned. Ref If you want to retrieve all files and folders, please use pageSize and pageToken. Please be careful about this.

Reference:

Scopes for Google Drive API

